# calculate the angle between two points in after effects

Tags: after-effects

I am trying to create an arrow with a line in after effects. The start point is always static, the end point can be moved with sliders and on the end point there is a triangle pointing in the direction the line is pointing.

The line itself is no problem: I used the pen tool to create a path, used create nulls from path and added sliders to the null that controls the end point.

The triangle part is what I can't seem to figure out. On the rotation property of the function:

```
var p1 = thisComp.layer("Start").transform.position;
var p2 = thisComp.layer("End").transform.position;
radiansToDegrees(Math.atan2(p1,p2);
```

(Start and End are the Nulls controlling the path)

I assume atan2 is the proper approach in this scenario but Ae gives me an error and the result of the final line is NaN. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: print p1 and p2

Comment: If you make the arrow a 3D layer (the layer it references doesn't have to be), you can use an orientation expression like this (you'll need google acct to view/download I think), and note how it flips, which hopefully won't matter: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1S_FamqUaNsEwFOxYP89Sx694diPa15wM?usp=sharing

Comment: Also note how the x and y rotations here were tweaked by 90 degrees to work with this particular (quickly done) set-up. If this works for you I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Late answer but try this:

```
p1 = thisComp.layer("Start").transform.position;
p2 = thisComp.layer("End").transform.position;

v = p2 - p1;

radiansToDegrees(Math.atan2(v[1], v[0]));
```

In your code there is a close parenthesis missing at the end, that's why the error.